# What's the pattern for calling requestAnimationFrame multiple times per frame?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, css-animations, requestanimationframe

I have a touch handler that may fire multiple times within a given 16ms time period. On each firing, I set a translate on the element based on the touch position, eg:

```
at 2ms, translate 20px
at 5ms, translate 40px
at 10ms, translate 50px
```

I understand that calls to rAF queue up, so all three will run for the next frame and set the element's transform property three times. This involves unnecessary extra work – all it needs to do is the most recent one (translate 50px). What's the best way to cancel the first two calls or turn them into no-ops?

Comment: rAF fires about 60 times per second. Touch events usually fire at the same speed as rAF (or fewer times/second than rAF). Are you sure you're getting up to 500 touch events per second (1000ms / 2ms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the best way to cancel the first two calls

Store the token returned by the latest `requestAnimationFrame`, and when you schedule a new handler call [`cancelAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame) with it.

> or turn them into no-ops?

You can just as easily use boolean flags that you check every time. Or maybe you even don't need to re-register a new handler but just can use the one that is already scheduled with the new data.